# Left join conditions collated from multiple tables in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My main table looks like:

[image]

Left joining on H1:

[image]

If H1 in main table does not match a value in right table append value from mapping 'H2' from the table below (Table3):
[image]

Final Result:

[image]

My current solution involves slicing out the NULLS after making the first join. Joining NULLS with Table 3 and appending it back to main table. However it is tedious and hogs memory.

```
result = Main.join(Table2, Main.H1==Table2.H1, 'left')
Slice = result.filter(result.R.isNull())
Slice = Slice.join(Table3, Slice.H2==Table3.H2, 'left')

finalresult = result.filter(~result.R.isNull()).union(Slice)
```

Please advise if there's a more efficient way to implement this.

Comment: Why not union tables 2 and 3, distinct the rows (Or if you have some other logic run a reduceByKey), and then join with table 1?

Comment: Well the whole idea is to only use values from Table3 ONLY if they are not available from first join of main table and table 2.

Comment: No problem with that. After you union tables 2 and 3 you reduceByKey and implement a logic that, if the same key is present in both tables, you only keep the value from table 2. With this method you only need to do one join which is much better in terms of performance than other suggested methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with **`left join`**, followed by **`inner join`**, and then use **`when/otherwise`** clause to **`replace null.`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F    
Main.join(Table2.withColumnRenamed("H2","H22"), ['H1'],'left').drop("H22")\
    .join(Table3.withColumnRenamed("R","R2"),['H2'])\
    .withColumn("R", F.when(F.col("R").isNull(), F.col("R2")).otherwise(F.col("R"))).drop("R2").show()

#+---+---+---+
#| H2| H1|  R|
#+---+---+---+
#|  B|  3|0.6|
#|  C|  5|0.2|
#|  A|  1|0.5|
#|  A|  2|0.4|
#|  A|  4|0.3|
#+---+---+---+
```

Comment: In this line ```.join(Table3.withColumnRenamed("R","R2"),['H2'])\``` Is the inner join between, Table 2 and table 3 OR Main table and table 3 OR Left Join result and table 3??

Comment: left join result and table 3

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the way you are merging:

```
result = Main.join(Table2, Main.H1==Table2.H1, 'left')
```

will have two columns named 'H1', one from Main table and other from Table2.

So, better way will be to merge the way Mohammad has mentioned. But, it can be further improved, if you use coalesce function.

```
Main.join(Table2.withColumnRenamed("H2","H22"), ['H1'],'left').drop("H22")\
.join(Table3.withColumnRenamed("R","R2"),['H2'])\
.withColumn("R", F.coalesce(F.col("R"), F.col("R2"))).drop("R2").show()
```

For details refer to this link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nZ5KiRuNfc